# Dynamic Searching for exact and partial matches in excel using option buttons

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, full-text-search, partial

I have the following code that allows me to search through the data on a table by using the option buttons I created that match the table headings. I can set the search criteria to be exact matches or partial. However, what I would like is to be able to search through different columns in the table without always having to go into the VBA code to toggle this option on and off. i.e some columns I would like an exact match, others I would like partial.

Any help on where I can amend the code below?

```
Sub SearchBox()

Dim myButton As OptionButton
Dim SearchString As String
Dim ButtonName As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim myField As Long
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim mySearch As Variant

'Load Sheet into A Variable
  Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Unfilter Data (if necessary)
  On Error Resume Next
    sht.ShowAllData
  On Error GoTo 0

'Filtered Data Range (include column heading cells)
  'Set DataRange = sht.Range("E5:H200") 'Cell Range
   Set DataRange = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range 'Table

'Retrieve User's Search Input
  'mySearch = sht.Shapes("UserSearch").TextFrame.Characters.Text 'Control Form
  mySearch = sht.OLEObjects("Hello").Object.Text 'ActiveX Control
  'mySearch = sht.Range("A1").Value 'Cell Input

'Determine if user is searching for number or text
  If IsNumeric(mySearch) = True Then
    SearchString = "=" & mySearch
  Else

  'change this to =* if you want to search for anything that containts mysearch rather than just mysearch
    SearchString = "=*" & mySearch & "*"

    End If

'Loop Through Option Buttons
  For Each myButton In sht.OptionButtons
    If myButton.Value = 1 Then
      ButtonName = myButton.Text
      Exit For
    End If
  Next myButton

'Determine Filter Field
  On Error GoTo HeadingNotFound
    myField = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ButtonName, DataRange.Rows(1), 0)
  On Error GoTo 0

'Filter Data
  DataRange.AutoFilter _
    Field:=myField, _
    Criteria1:=SearchString, _
    Operator:=xlAnd

'Clear Search Field
  'sht.Shapes("UserSearch").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "" 'Control Form
  sht.OLEObjects("Hello").Object.Text = "" 'ActiveX Control
  'sht.Range("A1").Value = "" 'Cell Input

Exit Sub

'ERROR HANDLERS
HeadingNotFound:
  MsgBox "The column heading [" & ButtonName & "] was not found in cells " & DataRange.Rows(1).Address & ". " & _
    vbNewLine & "Please check for possible typos.", vbCritical, "Header Name Not Found!"

End Sub


Sub ClearFilter()
'PURPOSE: Clear all filter rules

'Clear filters on ActiveSheet
  On Error Resume Next
  ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).AutoFilter.ShowAllData

  On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps easier to use the `Find` method which has a partial/whole argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify and try the below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim SearchValue As String, FullReport As String
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    'What i m looking for
    SearchValue = "Test"

    'Where to look for
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange

    For Each cell In rng

        If cell.Value = SearchValue Then
            If FullReport = "" Then
                FullReport = "The word " & SearchValue & " appears in " & "Column " & cell.Column & ", Row " & cell.Row & "."
            Else
                FullReport = FullReport & vbNewLine & "The word " & SearchValue & " appears in " & "Column " & cell.Column & ", Row " & cell.Row & "."
            End If
        End If

    Next cell

    MsgBox FullReport

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed list of columns, then simply move the code where you set the SearchString below the part where you determine which column you want to search and check the selected field against this list. However, I would suggest to put this is a separate function:

```
Function getSearchString(searchVal as variant, searchFieldName as string)
    If IsNumeric(searchVal) Then
        getSearchString = "=" & searchVal 
    ElseIf searchFieldName = "MyField1" _
        Or searchFieldName = "MyField2" _
        Or (... List all fields where you want to search partial) Then
        getSearchString = "=*" & searchVal & "*"
    Else
        getSearchString = "=" & searchVal
    End If
End Function
```

You call the function after setting the var `ButtonName`.

```
    searchStr = getSearchString(mySearch, ButtonName)
```

(you can of course think about a more sophisticated way to determine if or if not to use partial searching - or maybe add a CheckBox to let the user choose)

Comment: okay sorry to be a bother - would you mind helping me modify the code to implement? Not super sure in implementing the above

Comment: Pretty straightforward: **(1)** Remove the if-else part where you set the searchStr. **(2)** Add the call to the new function above the `Filter Data` - statements. **(3)** Copy&Paste the function somewhere in your module **(4)** Modify the `ElseIf`-Part of the function so that it checks for all your fields where you want to use partial search.

Comment: Thanks I get the process, but seem to get an error when calling the above    searchStr = getSearchString(mySearch, ButtonName) as variable not found. I amended this to SearchString which just threw another error this time in the fuction for mySearch

Comment: Sorry, did a mistake when copying the code from the VBA editor. Could you retry?

Comment: thanks managed to get it to work. There is one thing however - there is a column that has numbers/letters in it which I wanted a partial match on, however when put numbers in nothing appears. Not too much of an issue but curious if there is a workaround?

Comment: Maybe change the order: Take the `ElseIf`-Part as `If` and the `IsNumeric(searchVal)` as `ElseIf`

Comment: Hmm did the following:          
    If searchFieldName = "Portfolio Number" _
        Or searchFieldName = "Portfolio Name" _
       Then
        getSearchString = "=*" & searchVal & "*"
    ElseIf IsNumeric(searchVal) Then
    
        getSearchString = "=" & searchVal
           
     Else
     getSearchString = "=" & searchVal
    
        End If
    No luck it is okay dont think it is going to be a quick fix